# Deploy SQL Server Schema Changes using SQLCMD

Tags: sql-server

I'm using Visual Studio Team System 2008's Database tools to develop my databases. On my local dev machine, when I want to deploy schema changes to the SQL Server instance on my machine, I just use the Data --> Schema Compare feature of VS2008.

But with live databases I can't do this because I can't connect to the database directly from my machine and the server haven't got VS2008 installed.

So I was thinking about the SQLCMD tool. Isn't that what VS2008 uses "under the hood"?

I want to use as part of an automatic deployment strategy. I want to be able to publish SQL scripts generated by VS2008 to the server and have an application run scripts on the live database to update the schema.

**UPDATE**

**I'm trying to achieve automatic change script generation by taking the deploy script VS2008 Database Edition generates and comparing it against a live database. Only I want to do it through code, no tool or anything. It must be able to run from a Windows Service on the server.**

Answer (score 0):

SqlCmd would work. If you also want automatic versioning support you should check out [Tarantino.Net](http://code.google.com/p/tarantino/wiki/DatabaseChangeManagement), a database management tool that keeps track of which sql-files have already been run.

Comment: Do you know how to use SQLCMD to update the schema like VS2008 does?

Comment: You need only run the script using SQLCMD - the script is what actually "updates" the schema.  Here's an intro to SQLCMD:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170207.aspx

Comment: Yes I'm aware of that ;). But running the deployment script deletes the whole database and re-creates it with the new schema. It must do a comparison to see what the differences are, generate an update script which will update the database schema.

Comment: There is a tool from Red Gate called SqlCompare that does just that: http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm. Another option is to use the "Generate Change Scripts" feature of Sql Server each time you make a change to the database schema.

Comment: I updated my question, since it was rather un-clear what my question was.